# Getting the html content of a Gmail message twice when using Java IMAP

Tags: java, gmail, imap

As the title suggests, I'm trying to import emails from a gmail account and it's working rather well, but I seem to have a problem in my code where the content of the message appears twice in my output.

here's my code :

```
private String processMessage(Message m) throws IOException, MessagingException {
        String message = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Object o = m.getContent();

        if (o instanceof Multipart) {
            Multipart mm = (Multipart) m.getContent();
            for (int i = 0; i < mm.getCount(); i++) {

                BodyPart bp = mm.getBodyPart(i);
                Object bpo = bp.getContent();

                if (bpo instanceof String) {
                    sb.append(bpo);
                } 
            }
        } else if (o instanceof String) {
            sb.append(o);
        }
        String htmlMessage = sb.toString();
        message = htmlMessage.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");

        return message;
    }
```

This will return a nice formatted String containing the original text, but there will also be the complete message contained in a single line at the end of the String for some reason.

Say for the received message :
email
message
test

the output will be :
email 
message 
text

emailmessagetext

I'm guessing part of the multipart is a condensed version of the message content, but how can I avoid having this in the output?

P.S, if it's relevant, I'm getting the message by connecting to gmail via IMAP and then extracting all emails from a folder before processing them one by one.

```
folder.open(IMAPFolder.READ_ONLY);
messages = folder.getMessages();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most emails have a html body part and also a plain text body part (both).
You can use `getContentType` to get the content type of a body part

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the tip.
By simply adding  if (bp.getContentType().contains("TEXT/PLAIN")) before appending, I am now getting only what I need.